# ASPNETDB - How do I switch profile providers on the fly

Tags: membership, profile, provider, aspnetdb

I have a web site that uses ASPNETDB for membership/roles/profiles. The web site has some administration pages and I want to add a couple of new pages to be able to add/edit/delete users for the web site.

I have two different connection strings for the database, with different permissions/levels of security.

I want one ("ASPNETDBConnection") to be used solely for the web site login process, and other general use purposes for all visitors.

I want the other ("ASPNETDBConnectionAdmin") to be used for the add/edit/delete pages for logged in users.

I do not want to create a virtual directory/application (cannot - don't ask!).

I gather that while I can have only one profile, I can have multiple providers...

The following is taken from my current web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ASPNETDBConnection" applicationName="MyWebSite" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProviderAdmin" connectionStringName="ASPNETDBConnectionAdmin" applicationName="MyWebSite" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" enabled="true">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ASPNETDBConnection" applicationName="MyWebSite" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProviderAdmin" connectionStringName="ASPNETDBConnectionAdmin" applicationName="MyWebSite" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" enabled="true">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ASPNETDBConnection" applicationName="MyWebSite" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProviderAdmin" connectionStringName="ASPNETDBConnectionAdmin" applicationName="MyWebSite" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

My question is, how do I switch providers?

How do I change the membership provider from the default "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" to the alternative one, "AspNetSqlMembershipProviderAdmin" (dynamically?) in the code for the add/edit/user pages?

Et al for role & profile providers.

Any help in VB, rather than C# please.

Many Thanks...
Crimblepud

Answer (score 0):

Crimblepud

I tried to search, on it and even i tried making custom profiler,but not getting the idea, in between i found some useful resources,check it on

[Code Project on Profile](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/multi_profile.aspx)

[Profile Mechanism](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84376/inside-the-aspnet-user-profile-mechanism/)